# Install .dl_ Files

Tags: installation, printer

I'm trying to install a Ricoh printer and the drivers are a bunch of compressed .dll files.  How would I install that?

I've googled and can't figure out how to install a printer with .dl_ files.

Comment: try to use `expand` program (see `expand /help` for details)

Comment: Right click the `.inf` file that came with the `.dl_` files and select "Install"?

Comment: @Mokubai That doesn't work with Ricoh drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You've done step one by extracting the device drivers to a folder. Step two is to direct Windows to use it.

*NOTE: This presumes you have Windows 7 and you know the device's IP address. If you're on MacOs or Linux, you've got the wrong driver file.*

**If you're installing the printer fresh:**

1. Open Start, and open *"Devices and Printers"*
2. Click *"Add a printer"*.
3. Select *"Add a network, wireless or Bluetooth printer"*.
4. Click *"The printer that I want isn't listed"*
5. Select *"Add a printer using a TCP/IP address or hostname"*
6. Put in the printer's IP address in next to *"Hostname or IP Address"*. Unselect *"Query the printer and automatically select the driver to use."*.
7. Click *"Have Disk..."*.
8. Click *"Browse..."* and find that folder. Inside you'll have something like OEMSETUP.INF. Once you find it, double-click it.
9. Click *"OK"*.
10. You'll get a list of devices that driver supports. On the left select *"Ricoh"*, and on the right select the model you have. Click *"Next"*.
11. Click *"Finish"*.

**If you've already installed the printer:**

1. Open Start, and open *"Devices and Printers"*
2. Right-click on the printer, and select *"Printer Properties"* (**not** *"Properties"* at the bottom).
3. On the advanced tab, click *"New Driver"*.
4. Click *"Next"*.
5. Click *"Have Disk..."*.
6. Click *"Browse..."* and find that folder. Inside you'll have something like OEMSETUP.INF. Once you find it, double-click it.
7. Click *"OK"*.
8. You'll get a list of devices that driver supports. On the left select *"Ricoh"*, and on the right select the model you have. Click *"Next"*.
9. Click *"Finish"*.